# How to do Inner Join in SEQUELIZE?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two tables:

**Table 1**:

| ID | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |
| Second | row | row |

**Table 2**:

| ID | Number | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |
| Second | row | row |

I already have a model JS file for each.

This is for Table 1:

```
import  Sequelize  from "sequelize";
import db from './index.js';

const table1 =  db.define("table_1", {
        id : {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        }
    }, {
        schema: 'example',
        tableName: 'table1'
});

export default table1;
```

This is for Table 2:

```
import  Sequelize  from "sequelize";
import db from './index.js';

const table2 =  db.define("table_2", {
        id : {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        }
    }, {
        schema: 'example',
        tableName: 'table2'
});

export default table2;
```

I want to use Inner Join using Sequelize. I saw I could use raw SQL script, but since I'm using Sequelize, I wanted to make good use of that and just utilize it instead of using the raw SQL.

How do I do Inner Join for this one?

The SQL Script I'm going for is something like this:

```
SELECT    
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t2.email,
    t2.number,
    t2.status
FROM
    table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t2.email = 'test.test@test.com';
```

Again I'm looking for a way to do this in Sequelize instead of just using raw SQL.

Comment: Firstly you need to specify the relation between these two tables with `belongsTo`, `hasOne` \ `hasMany` methods. Then just use `include` inside your requests. More details here: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/

Comment: This ^ is correct. Adding a few points: adding `required: true` to your `include` request makes sure it's an INNER JOIN. Also you're trying to join 2 tables based on their primary keys, instead of a primary key & foreign key. Make sure you got the requirement right.

Comment: Relevant section in the docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#basics-of-queries-involving-associations

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
Product.hasOne(ProductCategory, { as: 'category', foreignKey: 'productId' });


const products = await Product.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: model.ProductCategory,
                as: 'category',
                required: true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Although this generates the correct query (as per checking), i'm getting 'Null' as a result. I'm using Async - Await. How is this so?

Comment: It means that your table1 does not have the id of table2. 
And if it works please let me know.